Stream canvas as video track, LiveKit
Im using Livekit client for flutter, and looking for an videocall app with draw feature thats allow you to draw something in a blank page im using canvas for that.
I want to publish a canvas instead of camera in Livekit videocall is that possible ?
// Create 30fps MediaStream
mediaStreamRef.current = canvasRef.current.captureStream(30);

// Publish the canvas video
const publishedTrack = mediaStreamRef.current.getVideoTracks()[0]
localParticipant.publishTrack(publishedTrack, {
  name: "video_from_canvas",
  source: Track.Source.Camera
})

this code resolve the problem in react, but i cannot found .captureStream function in dart

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
